# Golang http.Response gzip writer ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: go, gzip, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to gzip the proxied response from httputil.ReverseProxy -> ModifyResponse.
So I only have access to the http.Response object.

```
res.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(minified))
res.ContentLength = int64(len(minified))
res.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(minified)))
res.Header.Del("Content-Encoding")
```

This works just fine. But when I gzip the content I'll get a content-length-mismatch error.

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
gz.Write(minified)

readCloser := ioutil.NopCloser(&buf)
res.Body = readCloser

res.ContentLength = int64(buf.Len())
res.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(buf.Len()))
res.Header.Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
```

Can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong? The content-length is always 10 even when the input changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing your `gz` writer. It's possible issue. `gzip.Writer` [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#NewWriter) says:

> It is the caller's responsibility to call Close on the WriteCloser when done. Writes may be buffered and not flushed until Close.

So, try to add `gz.Close()` after you've completed writing data.