# Golang H2C Server doesn't write full body. Chrome says: "Server reset stream". Only occurs over http2 connection

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, http2

Most Recent Version of Go (1.153)

Below is the code for reproducibility. Please try to access https://easy-dp.ngrok.io to see the issue.

Here's what I did:

1. Create a Reverse Proxy accessing Gzipped/ Br encoded Content
2. Request a publicly available URL, I just grabbed Google Analytics
3. Attempt to encode and decode the response via an http2 connection with a proxy.modifyresponse function
4. Watch as content is dropped.

However, this only occurs under the following conditions:

- Under SSL, like with  https://easy-dp.ngrok.io
- When running a `proxy.ModifyResponse` function
- Decompressing and re-compressing the body (for example, just reading and rewriting the body to new bytes works)

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
    "golang.org/x/net/http2/h2c"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func ForwardAnalytics(req *http.Request) {
    req.URL.Scheme = "https"
    req.URL.Host = "www.google-analytics.com"
    req.Host = "www.google-analytics.com"
    req.URL.Path = "/analytics.js"
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
}

func ModifyAnalytics(r *http.Response) error {
    bytesFromBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
        gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(bytesFromBody))
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        defer gzipReader.Close()
        readableBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gzipReader)
        var b bytes.Buffer
        gzipWriter, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(&b, gzip.DefaultCompression)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        defer gzipWriter.Close()
        writtenLen, err := gzipWriter.Write(readableBytes)
        fmt.Println("Wrote ", writtenLen)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        r.ContentLength = int64(len(readableBytes))
        r.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(int64(len(readableBytes)), 10))
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(&b)

        return nil
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}


func handleProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    proxy := httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Director: ForwardAnalytics
    }
    proxy.ModifyResponse = ModifyAnalytics
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)

}

func main() {
    h2s := &http2.Server{
        IdleTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
    }
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc( "/", handleProxy)
    s := &http.Server{
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:       10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:      30 * time.Second,
        Addr:              "localhost:8456",
        Handler:           h2c.NewHandler(mux, h2s),
    }
    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

I expect to see the ability to open the bytes, modify them, and update the response body on an H2C connection

#### What did you see instead?

Two things of note happen:

1. Chrome gives a nice little error that expands upon what's going on

```
{"params":{"description":"Server reset stream.","net_error":"ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR","stream_id":5},"phase":0,"source":{"id":1493828,"start_time":"732370299","type":1},"time":"732375561","type":224},
```

2. Under the normal http connection, there's no problem, but under the https connection the script may or may not print out to a certain length. Sometimes it doesn't print at all, sometimes it prints about 30%.

This is a cross browser issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Content-Length header indicates the size of the entity body in the message, in bytes. The size includes any content encodings (the Content-Length of a gzip-compressed text file will be the compressed size, not the original size).

[src](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42225#issuecomment-717088912)

I thought I had tried this but kept running into `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` because of how I was closing my gzip writer. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613920/golang-http-response-gzip-writer-err-content-length-mismatch)

Final handler looked like this:

```golang
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
        gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(bytesFromBody))
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        defer gzipReader.Close()
        readableBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gzipReader)
        var b bytes.Buffer
        gzipWriter, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(&b, gzip.DefaultCompression)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        writtenLen, err := gzipWriter.Write(readableBytes)
        gzipWriter.Close() // This was the culprit. It needed to be closed here
        fmt.Println("Wrote ", writtenLen)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        r.ContentLength = int64(b.Len())
        r.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(int64(b.Len()), 10))
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(&b)
        return nil
    }
```